# SQLite-Net Query does not return expected result

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

I have a strange problem with a query. The query looks like that:

```
var query =
"select article.* from article left join articledetails on article.ArticleDetailsId = articledetails.Id "
+ $"where article.SUPPLIER_AID like '%{searchContextQuery}%' "
+ $"or articledetails.Description_Short like '%{searchContextQuery}%' "
+ $"or articledetails.Description_Long like '%{searchContextQuery}%' "
+ $"or articledetails.KeywordAsString like '%{searchContextQuery}%' ";

var result = connection.Query<Article>(query);
```

When searchContextQuery is filled with e.g. "M12GG−0 GREASE GUN XXX" there should be one line of result. I am retrieving the expected response, when I execute exact that query manually in SQLiteStudio on the very same database.

I also tried

```
var xyz = connection.Execute(query);
```

to make sure, that there is no problem with casting values or assigning values to my Article model class. It also results in a 0 result. That gives no sense to me ;(

Can someone give me a hint?

best regards,
Chris

Comment: And your connection string is?

Comment: does any query work for You ? or only this specific one is broken ?

Comment: Sorry,i forgot.to add, that i am using WinRT (Windows 8.1 App), so i am not using a connection string, i create a SQLiteConnection with Read/Write option directly to the path of the db. Other query work well. It's only that specific one. If i use a shorter "searchContextQuery" like "M12" it works as expected.